# Basic rails search not rendering results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Rails newbie here. I'm trying to implement a basic search function in my app and I'm not having any luck getting the search results to render in my partial. I've looked online at rails guides, scoured the forums here, experimented with various tutorials with little success.

As I mentioned, Rails newbie here, so I'm sure my code is probably pretty ugly. Any hints on how to follow proper etiquette will be greatly appreciated. :)

Post Controller

```
def index
  @posts = Post.ransack(params[:query], load:true).result
end

def show
  @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
end

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :image, :slug)
end

def search_params
  params.permit(:search_title, :search_body)
end
```

routes.rb

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
 ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

 resources :posts

 root to: 'posts#index', as: :home
```

Post Model

```
 belongs_to :category

 extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, :use => [:slugged, :finders]

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :body, presence: true
  validates :image, presence: true

 def self.search_posts(search)
  if search
   where(["title LIKE ?","%#{search}%"])
  else
   all
  end
 end
end
```

app/views/posts/index.html.erb

```
 <%= form_tag posts_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Posts" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
  <% if @posts.present? %>
  <%= render 'posts/show' %>
  <% else %>
  <p>We cannot find posts containing the term(s) <%= params[:search] %>. Please try again.</p>
 <% end %>
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'friendly_id'
```

I believe that's all the relevant code. Please let me know if you need  anything additional.

As you can see I add Posts via activeadmin so I'm not sure if that has any impact on this. Everything works normally and I get the checkmark in the url which I believe is telling me that it found a match but I'm trying to have it go to my show partial in the posts view but nothing happens.

Edit: Thanks for all of your responses. I tried each one but without success. However I believe that the issue is bigger than simply learning the ins and outs of a gem. I need to take some online classes to bone up more on the fundamentals. I will leave this post open and add a working solution to help out others once I've got a better handle on the basics. Thanks again all! :)

Edit_2: Answer is posted below.

Comment: A few things: 1) `params[:query]` seems like it will be `nil` since you called the field `search`  2) I have no idea what `load: true` is for but I have a feeling it will cause issues. (`result` will load the data for you) 3) `search_posts` means nothing in this context so it is just noise in the question. `ransack` will search using predications like `name_eq: value` so you need to name your search fields accordingly.

Comment: 4) in your view  you have to pass the collection to the render so it knows what to use. Generally this is better done as `<%= render @posts %>` with a partial called `_post.html.erb` as /posts/show most likely uses an instance variable `@post` (shown in the controller action) rather than a local variable `post` which the call to render would yield based on the class name of the object.

Comment: First off, thanks for the quick reply. Secondly it seems that I'm completely missing the boat here with Ransack. I thought I did my homework but apparently not. I'll have to do some more research after I run some errands. You've pointed me in the right direction and I appreciate it.

Comment: I'd recomend you to read the guide about rendering https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections specially that title about rendering collections of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty folks, after much head bashing and research, I managed to come up with an UGLY solution but it's a good starting point for anyone struggling with this same issue.

Post Controller

```
def search
  if params[:post].present?
   @post = Post.search(params[:post])
  if @post #meaning if it's not nil or nothing matches the search
   render 'posts/results'
  end
  else
   flash[:danger] = "You have entered an empty search"
   redirect_to 'Home'
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :posts

  root to: 'posts#index', as: :home

  get 'search_posts', to: 'posts#search'
```

models/post.rb

```
 validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 50 }
 validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 300 }

 def self.search(search)
  where("lower(title) like ? OR lower(body) like ?", "%#{search.downcase}%", "%#{search.downcase}%")
 end
```

View

```
<h3>Search for Posts</h3>
 <div id="post-lookup">
  <%= form_tag search_posts_path, method: :get, id: "post-lookup-form" do %>
   <div class="form-group row no-padding text-center col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-10">
     <%= text_field_tag :post, params[:post], placeholder: "Post Lookup", autofocus: true, class: "form-control search-box input-lg" %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <%= button_tag(type: :submit, class: "btn btn-lg btn-success") do %>
       Look up a post
    <% end %>
    </div>
   </div>
  <% end %>
 </div>
 <% if @post %>
  <% @post.each do |post| %>
   <div class="well results-block">
    <strong>Title:</strong><%= post.title %>
    <strong>Body:</strong><%= post.body %>
   </div>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

As I said, ugly. But it's at least functional. I hope that this helps someone out there. Now I'm off to clean this glorious mess up and add some AJAX. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not passing correct params for ransack search. You can try as follow:

app/views/posts/index.html.erb

```
<%= search_form_for @search, url: posts_path do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-xl-5">
      <%= f.label :posts_name_cont, 'Search by Product Name' %>
      <%= f.search_field :posts_name_cont, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-xl-3 pt-4 pr-md-5 pb-2"> 
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-large mx-auto col-12 mb-2 mt-2 float-right" type="submit" name="action">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% if @posts.any? %>
  <% @posts.each do |p| %>
    <%= p.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Post Controller

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  @search = @posts.ransack(params[:q])
  @posts = @search.result.order(:created_at)
end
```

You can also check more details about searching options here [Ransack gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack)